# How to open a browser window from the Google Calendar Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to open a browser window using a Google Calendar add-on.

I've seen apps doing this, but I can't find any documents to support this option.

The methods found in Google Docs only have options to use the SpreadsheetApp, but this is not available in the calendar.

Any idea how this is achievable?

This is the expected behavior I'm looking for.

Upon clicking "NEW", a browser window should open.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 var button = CardService.newTextButton()
.setText("OPEN")
.setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
.setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
    .setUrl("https://google.com")
    .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
    .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON));
```

This is what I was looking for.
No need to use SpreadsheetApp